# I installed Netbeans 11 from store and now it doesn't show on applications

Tags: launcher, netbeans, ubuntu-store

In my Ubuntu 19.04 I installed Netbeans IDE 11.1 from the store. In store it shows as installed and I can start it from there. If I try to start it from 'show apps' where you can search app by name it doesn't show in it at all.

Comment: Do the instructions in this link help you? https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-netbeans-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Comment: Can you start netbeans, you write command "netbeans" on terminal?

Answer (score 1):

Linux maintains a .desktop file for each menu items. It stores all the desktop file at `/usr/share/applications`. You have to go there and verify whether there is a correct desktop file for netbeans or not. If not then you have to create one and put there. It can be of any name but its extension should be .desktop. A desktop file looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Netbeans IDE
Exec=<cmd to start netbeans>
Icon=<path to NetBeans icon>
Type=Application
Categories=Programming;IDE;
```

Its simple to install any software from software center, But I personally prefer to manually download and install any software instead of installing it from the software center, At the software center, they usually are not the latest version.

Comment: Store installs netbeans 11 as a snap application so I do not know where it is actually installed and therefore can't know the exact path to exec.

Comment: Check once /opt directory.

Comment: not at /opt only google there. I also uninstalled it from store and reinstalled from command line (snap command) as instructed by Graham in this post.

Comment: then there would be a /snap directory in which it would have got installed.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up downloading Netbeans from Apache and installing it from there. Problem solved.